# Execute Pl SQL conditions in a column and get return value

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tables used:

**RULE ENGINE Table:**

[image]

**POINT Table**

[image]

I am trying to execute rules in RULE ENGINE table where some of the data(d1.sm.n1,d2.sm.n2..etc) are referred from POINT table.

The value of 'XSGSY' depends upon rule in RULE column.

Note: These rules follow plsql syntax.

I tried to extract data values(d1.sm.n1) and added to rule:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN If ''Yes'' = ''Yes'' OR 
''Yes'' = ''Yes'' then return ''Y''; else return ''N''; end if; END;'
```

then execute rules using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` , but it was not working.

> ERROR: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression

Also tried with function and got error:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace function express return 
VARCHAR2(10)  
  BEGIN If ''Yes'' = ''Yes'' OR ''Yes'' = ''Yes'' 
 then return ''Y''; else return ''N''; end if; 
END express;' INTO l_output;
```

> ERROR: ORA-06546: DDL statement is executed in an illegal context

Comment: A procedure or anonymous block cannot return a value; a DDL statement doesn't have any output for `into` to handle, and you don't (and can't) call the function you are creating. Looks like you need to use bind variables for both inputs and result, but quite how is hard to tell from that single statement. Showing the code around that, and how it relates to the rule engine (?), would help. Please post formatted text rather than images.

Comment: It might be possible to implement this using object types such that the Rules Engine table contained actual functions instead of text strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design looks flawed.I presume you want to extract result of a dynamically constructed PL/SQL block into a local variable. If so, you may use an `USING OUT variable`  option.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
l_x  VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN If ''Yes'' = ''Yes'' OR 
''Yes'' = ''Yes'' then :x := ''Y''; else :x := ''N''; end if; END;' USING OUT l_x;
dbms_output.put_line(l_x);
END;
/

Y


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```